# String reverse program throws exception

Tags: c++

```
// ExampleCodes.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include<stdio.h>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;    

char* stringReverse(char* s)    
{    

    char temp, *p,*q;    
    q = s;    
    while( *(++q));    
    for( p = s; p &lt; --q; p++)    
    {    
        temp = *p;    
        *p = *q;     
        *q = temp;    
    }    
    return s;    
}    


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])    
{    

    stringReverse("StringReverse");    
    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Indent your source code with four spaces to get it to display correctly.

Comment: Almost exactly the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/480555/modifying-c-string-constants , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1614723/why-is-this-c-code-causing-a-segmentation-fault , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124600/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-using-pointers and many more...

Comment: Shouldn't the compiler atleast give you a warning about passing a const char* to a char* parameter.

Comment: You seem to have accidentally omitted your question.

Comment: @Alexander Rafferty: The type of string literals in C is `char []`, which decays to `char *` (this despite them being unmodifiable).  This is because string literals pre-date the `const` keyword.

Comment: @caf: Actually this is somewhat wrong. A string literal is of the type `const char[]`. But, yes, there's a (deprecated) conversion from a string literal to `char*`, to allow old code to compile.

Comment: I suppose this is missing a `homework` tag? Because otherwise the answer would be "use `std::reverse()`!"

Comment: @sbi: The C standard just says the elements of the array that make up a character string literal have type `char`.  There is no mention of `const`.  I am led to believe that this is different in C++, however.

Comment: @sbi: In C (when we started the discussion, this question was tagged `C`), a string literal is explicitly specified as being an lvalue (which implies you can legally take its address with `&`).  It's an array type with elements of type `char`, which gives it type `char [N]` where N is the length including nul terminator.  This means it decays to type `char *` when used in most expressions.

Comment: @caf: I didn't know this was tagged `C`. When I came this already was a `C++` question. Anyway, I already said I'm quite messed up on the issue, so you might be right for C++, too.

Answer (score 8):

You can't modify constant string literals.

```
stringReverse("StringReverse");
```

You could use a character array instead:

```
char str[] = "StringReverse";
```

Answer (score 5):

String literals, like `"StringReverse"`, are not allowed to be modified in C.  Use an array:

```
char str[] = "StringReverse";
stringReverse(str);
```

Note that your `stringReverse()` function has undefined behaviour if you feed it a zero-length string.

Answer (score 0):

You never allocated any memory for p. You can try `p = new char[sizeof(s)];`

Comment: `p` doesn't need its own memory - the function reverses a string in-place.

Comment: Okay, my mistake. His function doesn't seem to make much sense to me. I think that it could be changed to be make more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should write something like this:

```
// in - string to reverse
// out - buffer for reversed string
// l - size of in

StringReverse(char* in, char* out, int l) {
  for (int i=0;i<l;i++) {
    out[l-(i+1)] = in[i];
  }
}
```

*There is very very little to no speed difference between [] and *(p++) / *(p--)

Answer (score -1):

Well I was going to clean up the awful source in the OP but instead I'll just post a cleaner version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void reverse_string(char *s)
{
    char *q = s + strlen(s);
    for (char *p = s; p < --q; p++)
    {
        char temp = *p;
        *p = *q;
        *q = temp;
    }
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "StringReverse";
    reverse_string(s);
    puts(s);
    return 0;
}
```

I hope for your sake Amit that you're still a student.

### Update0

This is actually pure C, so learn from and awe at its performance but don't start writing C++ like this.

Comment: I'm half tempted to downvote for "cleaning up" code, and then adding an xor hack.

Comment: I'm half-tempted to downvote just for the xor hack. Unless you've got a benchmark showing that xor is universally faster than using a temporary, don't bother with it.

Comment: The xor stuff was just for kicks, I'll remove it.

Comment: Still, this is a C++ question. What's with `std::swap(*p,*q)`? And in C++, those headers should be `<cstdio>` and `<cstring>`, and it's `std::strlen()`.

Comment: @sbi: Yeah that's true. Suddenly I don't feel like doing C++ (that was quick, I hadn't started yet) ;]