# Is it possible write a function that can reverse a string without using a buffer string?

Tags: c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to reverse a string in place in c using pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124600/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-using-pointers)

The interview question was to write a function called `revstr` which can take a string and reverse it without using a buffer string i.e involving pointers. How do I do this?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124600/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-using-pointers

Comment: My idea was like is there a way to read the pointer in the opposite direction , that will just achieve the goal ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Iterate from beginning and end simultaneously, swap characters.

```
void revstr(char * str) {
  int right = strlen(str) - 1;
  int left = 0;
  while (left < right) {
    char c = str[right];
    str[right] = str[left];
    str[left] = c;
    ++left;
    --right;
  }
}
```

Optionally you can use xor tricks to swap without an intermediate char:

```
str[right] ^= str[left];
str[left] ^= str[right];
str[right] ^= str[left];
```

This is a purely nonsensical way of doing a swap - the only reason to use this construct is an artificial requirement saying that you can't store string data in intermediate variables and you can't call external functions.

Comment: -0.5 for xor swap. I know it works in this case, since your condition is `left < right`, but it's premature pessimization. Unless there's a proven need to make the code slower (e.g. the profiler has identified this as a cold spot), why use it?

Comment: @Steve Jessop: The OPs "without using a buffer string" - just demonstrating that you can do it without intermediate storage of the data.

Comment: Nothing in the C standard guarantees that the normal swap uses intermediate storage, or that the xor swap doesn't, just that one uses an object and the other uses rvalues, so there's a difference in the abstract machine. And anyway, you're "using" more storage for `left` and `right` than for `c`. I'll give you +1 if you edit to "silly xor tricks" ;-p

Comment: @Steve Jessop: No *explicit* extra storage of string data then :P - But you're right, there should be a warning in front of such silly constructs, otherwise people might actually use them in real code.

Answer (score 1):

I think that at least you need a char variable to perform a swap operations.
You can use something like that:

```
char buf[SIZE];
   int i ;
   char swap;
      for ( i = 0 ; i < SIZE / 2; i++){
   swap = buf[i];
   buf[i] = buf[SIZE - i];
   buf[SIZE -i] = swap;
   }
```

Comment: Thanks this was exactly my program in he iview . Hope the iviwer likes it .

Comment: Is it possible to read the pointer in the reverse order ? I mean that would just read the string too .

Comment: @Nishant: i didn't understand exactly what you mean, anyway you can of course starting the cicle from the end of the array and decrementing the pointer.