# String reverse using pointers

Tags: c, string, pointers, reverse, using

I'm trying to reverse a string using pointers.When i try to print the reversed string instead of getting DCBA i'm getting out only as BA?Can anyone help me on this?

```
#include<stdio.h>
void reverse(char *);
void main()
{
  char str[5] = "ABCD";
  reverse(str);
}

void reverse(char *str)
{
  char *rev_str = str;
  char temp;
  while(*str)
      str++;
  --str;

  while(rev_str < str)
  {
      temp = *rev_str;
      *rev_str = *str;
      *str = temp;   
      rev_str++;      
      str--;
  }
  printf("reversed string is %s",str);
}
```

Comment: Think about what `str` is pointing to at the time you call `printf`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse a string in place in c using pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124600/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-using-pointers)

Answer (score 2):

You're losing your pointer to the beginning of the string, so when you print it out you're not starting from the first character, because `str` no longer points to the first character.  Just put in a placeholder variable to keep a pointer to the beginning of the string.

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
  char *begin = str; /* Keeps a pointer to the beginning of str */
  char *rev_str = str;
  char temp;
  while(*str)
      str++;
  --str;

  while(rev_str < str)
  {
      temp = *rev_str;
      *rev_str = *str;
      *str = temp;   
      rev_str++;      
      str--;
  }
  printf("reversed string is %s\n", begin);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
char* strrev(chr* src)
{      
       char* dest
       int len=0 ;    //calculate length of the src string
       int index=0 ;  // index for dest (output) string
       int rindex=0; //Index to be counted from end toward beginning of src string

       //Calculate length of the string
       //Keep iterating till it reaches to null char '\0'

       while(*(src+len) != '\0')
       { len++ }

       //pointing rindex at the last character of src string 
       rindex=len-1;

       
       //Start copying from last char of src string at first index of dest array
       // Copying second last char of src string at second index of dest array and so on ..


       while(rindex > =0)
       {
           *(dest+index) = *(src + rindex)
            index++;
            rindex--;
       }

   // Finally covert array of char into string , by inserting a null char at the end of dest array

      *(dest+index) = '\0';


return dest;
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.