# Reversing a String With Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm attempting to write a simple program that will reverse a users input utilizing pointers. This is my first time working with pointers and in theory my program seems like it would work: have an array, write the users input to the array, point one pointer to the head and the other to the end and have the while loop do the rest. However, my program isn't working properly. My question is, what exactly am I doing wrong?

Heres my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    char user_input[1000] = " ";

    cout << "Enter a word to be reversed: " << endl;
    cin >> user_input;

    int myChar = sizeof(user_input) - 1;

    char *start = user_input;
    char *end = user_input + myChar - 1;

    while (start < end) {
        char save = *start;
        *start = *end;
        *end = save;

        start++;
        end--;
    }

    cout << user_input;

} 

And my output: 

Enter a word to be reversed: 
hello <--- my input
      <--- no output
```

Comment: `My question is, what exactly am I doing wrong?` You're not using STL, `std::string` and `std::reverse`

Comment: possible duplicate to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302524/string-reverse-using-pointers

Comment: And what happens if I enter a word with more than 999 characters?

Comment: @ChristianHackl - where would you find one? ;)

Comment: @owacoder: German grammar allows compounds of infinite length. Let's see... "Computerproblemlösungskompetenzseminarlehrergehaltsverhandlungspausengrund." - Reason for pausing negotations about the salary of seminar teachers for competence in solving computer problems. You can extend this at will and even make it recursive. (But before you go on and do so, mind that even though the grammar allows it, good style is a different story :))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The line

```
int myChar = sizeof(user_input) - 1;
```

should be

```
#include <string.h>

int myChar = strlen(user_input);
```

Currently, you are reversing all 1000 characters in your array. The characters beyond the end of your inputted string are not initialized, so you should only reverse the number of characters the user input. `strlen()` finds the length for you.

Another alternative: use the standard library.

Comment: Thank you! I missed strlen() in my studies.

Answer (score 3):

`sizeof(user_input)` is always 1000 since `user_input` is an array of 1000 1-byte elements.

You need to use `strlen` instead. It returns the index of the terminating null character.

Answer (score 2):

declare user_input as 
char *user_input=new char[1000]

---

> **so what is the problem ??**

---

well the problem is when you take input from user in user_input it take it as user_input[0]
so either run a for loop from 0 to n-1 or use my way given above
moreover output is still errorneous  that i will leave for u .....

Comment: Thank you! I know understand better.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write a strlen function by yourself.
The end of the user's input would be the index of the first 0 as an int or '\0' AS a char.