# How to reverse byte array using pointers

Tags: c#, arrays, performance, pointers

Working on Windows OS and C# (means little endian) so no need for extra checks.

How can I increase speed of reversing an array of bytes using pointers?

Instead of a normal for loop:

```
const int  value = 133;
var bArr = new byte[]{ 0, 0, 0 , value };
int Len = bArr.Length;
var rrAb = new byt[Len];

for(int idx=0; idx<bArr.Length;idx++)
          rrAb[idx] = bArr[--Len];
```

[String reverse using pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10302524/string-reverse-using-pointers)

Comment: did you tried Array.Reverse?

Comment: @Gusman I want to do it not use it ... (;

Comment: Then a pointer will not speed up your code, accessing an array element is like using a pointer, same speed

Comment: Are you certain it can be made faster with pointers? .NET is a little weird with pointers, since everything is already a pointer underneath, so by declaring an explicit pointer into the heap-allocated array you can actually end up increasing the time (not to mention even worse than normal optimization because the compiler treats unsafe code as unoptimizable).  If you want it faster, @Gusman is right on Array.Reverse, since it is implemented in low-level native C.

Comment: @Gusman extra method call i'll stick to for loop within same code block... i guess it's the best

Comment: what do you mean with "extra method call"?

Comment: @Gusman
within the same method I am executing another call to `Array.Revers();` rather `for`looping within the same scope/code execution , the control moves to the `Array.Reverse()` so it's an extra method call - extra time not true ?

Comment: I doubt it's extra time, Array.Reverse works in unmanaged pure C, get for sure the functions used inside will be a lot faster, so the call to Reverse is not noticeable vs the benefit of the c function.

Comment: @Gusman
I am asking another question as it's out of scope here, regarding the result of the timing I have made. using `Stopwatch` the results are odd, they're based on position of the code . if my code is first is the winner if the code I assume is slower - is first , then it's the winner

Comment: That's because of caching and initialization, do a loop of tests first and let the framework "settle" everything and do again the test (without restarting the proces, of course). Also, remember other process can interfere, garbage collection also... doing a real performance test is really hard...

Comment: @Gusman (I am suspended  out of school ) "they" don't let me open a new one on the tests I have made but I couldn't paste it here as it's out of scope, though the issue is reading int32 out of MMF accessor vs coding it all including the handles etc' thanks for referring to the `Stopwatch` - benchmarking issue

Comment: i have saved valuable 50% increase in performance using win32 DLL  call and unsafe and the access time cut into half

Comment: @Gusman i have done it within x100 for Loop, its consistent  which of the tested code is the first to execute , wins

Comment: but do you have an external loop? i mean *external loop -> ((test loop for method one) -> (test loop for method two))* in this way you will execute the loops more than once, and for the results you use the result from the last iteration of the external loopç

Comment: @Gusman never mind i suspect i have made my best to strip down the code the standard .Net into minimal no checks on pointless suspections , not instanciating extra unneeded objects and i think it should surely be faster , funny results behavior, i need to do a benchmarking degree solely apart from studying how to code.

Comment: *minimal no checks on pointless suspections* you will be amazed how many tons of internal checks does .net for retrieving values XD

Comment: @Gusman thanks i'll separate them. didn't think of it , i will calculate the time devided by counter, check on average . so for loop on each of them then

Comment: @Gusman now the results are for the .net as the compiler (i suspect ) is **not really** working on the dot net line , i think it says ha, this is a function call to do same thing , i will make them think i worked 100 times and set the result once... should be ok cause they will get same value ...

Comment: @Gusman hey you here ? i have finally tested it right my new approach(win32) is 0.2 the of total time reading  from+writing to mmf. than convansionall tested on top & on bottom of each other X5 faster !

Comment: So you finally passed the array to a c dll to reverse it?

Comment: @Gusman
yep and using bit converter, though my important test is ..was not reading mmf position into an  int but the more important time consuming actual data`byte[]` read write !

Comment: well, using w32 c of course will be always faster than managed code, but I don't get why you need to use bitconverter

Comment: @thanks for your help Mr. Gusman

Comment: @Gusman {0,0,0,13} to int ? reverse via `Aray.Reverse()` , then convert via bit converter, not efficient?

Comment: Oh, well, you can use pointers for that and it will be faster: fixed(byte* data = rrAb[0])value = STAR((inSTAR)data); I assume you already have the array fixed so no need to fix it again. replace STAR with an asterisk, the comments where removing them and setting the cntent as italic XD

Comment: @Gusman so you took reversed used it with fixed not the inintial slice but the reversed ok sure so `Aray.Reverse()` on the slice, fix slice, cast it with the `* ` as i did it (thinking fix is expencive),actually i need retest it cause i might did benchmark wrong(read int task), i'll test read int again in a minute

Comment: @Gusman ok for read /write `int` , use .net (don't know how amazing 32 ticks vs ~1k via win32), and for arrays(data) use what ever you can achieve as fast solution ,(as i did till final test anyway) ...

Comment: @Gusman  I'm going to check source of `UnmanagedMemoryAccessor.ReadInt32()` http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/unmanagedmemoryaccessor.cs,2df5d6bb6e2dd5ce