# Reverse a string not running in MinGW

Tags: c++, c, string, pointers

I have written the code to reverse a string. I think the logic is correct. I can compile it, but I am unable to run it. I am trying to use MinGW on windows. Can someone point out what the  problem might be?

```
 void reverse(char * start, char * end){
    char ch;
    while(start != end){
        ch = *start;
        *start++ = *end;
        *end-- = ch;
    }
 }

 int main(){
    char *c = (char *)"Career";
    int length = strlen(c);
    reverse(c,c+length-1);
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: So, your subject says it won't compile, but the body says you CAN compile but can't run.  Which is it, and can you be more specific about the problem you are having?  Also note that `char *c = (char *)"Career";` will be a read-only string in memory.  Try declaring it as a `char c[] = ....`

Comment: "Can someone point out what the problem might be?" -- Yes: the problem is your poor description and your failure to state what error you're getting.

Comment: And after you make it modifiable, use `std::reverse`.

Comment: Well I just get "a.exe" stopped working..

Comment: Which language? C or C++?

Comment: C++ ... I am using g++ in MinGW on Windows ..

Comment: You should probably tag the question with just C++, for future reference. The languages are different. In fact, I wonder why you are using C strings instead of C++ `std::string`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reverse a string in place in c using pointers?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2124600/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-place-in-c-using-pointers)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are passing a literal to your function and attempting to modify literals is undefined behaviour.

Make a modifiable string like this:

```
char c[] = "Career";
```

On top of that, `reverse` only works when you have an odd number of characters in your string. Your `while` condition is wrong. It should be:

```
while(start < end)
```

Your code said:

```
while(start != end)
```

and if your string has an even number of characters, that condition is always true. Hence the loops until you get a segmentation fault because `start` and `end` point outside the input string.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot change a string literal since it's placed in read-only memory.

Try declaring `c` as `char c[] = "Career";`

Comment: I made the changes but still it is not running .. I just get -- "a.exe" stopped working .. no error ..

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code did not compile is that you need to add

```
#include <string.h>
```

to the top of the file, to define the `strlen` function.

Also

```
while(start != end){
```

generates a

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

error for strings that are an even number of characters long.

Change this to

```
while(start < end){
```

and that error will go away.

Here's a complete working version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

 void reverse(char * start, char * end){
    char ch;
    while(start < end){
        ch = *start;
        *start++ = *end;
        *end-- = ch;
    }
 }

 int main(){
    char c[] = "Career";
    int length = strlen(c);
    reverse(c,c+length-1);
    printf("c=%s\n", c);
 }
```