# Reading function pointer syntax

Tags: c++, function-pointers

Everytime I look at a C function pointer, my eyes glaze over.  I can't read them.

From [here](http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/cpp/cpp_mfc/tutorials/article.php/c9855), here are 2 examples of function pointer TYPEDEFS:

```
typedef int (*AddFunc)(int,int);
typedef void (*FunctionFunc)();
```

Now I'm used to something like:

```
typedef vector<int> VectorOfInts ;
```

Which I read as

```
typedef vector<int> /* as */ VectorOfInts ;
```

But I can't read the above 2 typedefs.  The bracketing and the asterisk placement, it's just not logical.

Why is the * beside the word AddFunc..?

Comment: There is a nice explanation for reading function-pointer types at the end of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250397/interpretation-of-int-a3/2250448#2250448

Comment: If you don't care about getting a language lawyer, you can just use `identity`. Like `typedef identity<int(int, int)>::type *AddFuncPtr;`

Comment: @Johannes: Great idea, it "just" leaves `identity<>` to be standardized and implemented by every vendor. And it's not exactly that much of an improvement over C's declaration syntax...

Comment: @sbi: But then it gets you as close to `typedef FnType* FnPtrType` as it gets with C++ declarations.

Comment: And in C++0x you can do  `typedef alias<int(int, int)> *AddFuncPtr;` with template aliases.

Comment: @gf: I understand that this gets you as close to what other typedefs look. But it's still far from being ideal, and that's whyt I was complaining about. @Johannes: Nice to see this implemented in C++11.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual type of the first one is

```
int (*)(int,int);
```

(that is, a pointer to a function that takes two parameters of type `int` and returns an `int`)

The `*` identifies it as a function pointer.  `AddFunc` is the name of the typedef.

[cdecl](http://cdecl.org/) can help with identifying particularly complex type or variable declarations.

Comment: This is the weirdest thing ever!  So if we have `float (*GetPtr1(const char opCode))(float, float)`, that is a function named `GetPtr1` who returns `float(*) (float,float)`.  I find the second easier to read, why doesn't the syntax go `float(*)(float,float) GetPtr1(const char opCode);`?  That would be [hella](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QtTj4cramPM) easier to read imo!

Answer (score 5):

When you're comprehending it, just ignore the `typedef`, the parentheses around the function name, and the asterisk in front of the name.  Then you have `int AddFunc(int,int);`.

The point of the parentheses in `(*functionName)` is to specifically group the `*` with the name of the typedef.  The `*` is necessary to indicate that this is a function *pointer*.

So any function that takes two `int`s as arguments and returns an `int` complies to the `AddFunc` "interface", if you will.  Likewise, any function accepting no arguments are returning void can be used for a `FunctionFunc`.

Answer (score 3):

> I read `typedef vector<int> /* as */ VectorOfInts ;`

It's probably better if you see a `typedef` as an ***object definition with a `typedef` put in front***:

- `int i;` defines an ***integer object***
  `typedef int t;` defines an *integer **type***.
- `vector<int> v;` defines a ***vector object***
  `typedef vector<int> v;` defines a *vector **type***.
- `int (*AddFunc)(int,int)` defines a ***function pointer***
  `typedef int (*AddFunc)(int,int)` defines a *function pointer **type***.

C's declaration syntax, inherited by C++, is a mess. I agree that `typedef int (*)(int,int) AddFunc;` would make more sense. But C's declaration syntax is 40 years old, has never changed, and never will. You'd better get used to it.

Answer (score 2):

Function declarations look like this:

```
int AddFunc(int,int);
void FunctionFunc();
```

A typedef defining a function type looks the same, just with `typedef` in front:

```
typedef int AddFunc_t(int,int);
typedef void FunctionFunc_t();
```

To define a pointer to such a function type, there needs to be an additional `*` with additional parenthesis to specify where that `*` belongs to:

```
typedef int (*pAddFunc_t)(int,int);
typedef void (*pFunctionFunc_t)();
```

(The `*` is always right before the typename/variable that gets defined as a pointer.)

To read such a function pointer proceed in the opposite direction: leave out the `(* ... )` around the type name and the `typedef` in front. The result then looks like a normal function declaration of the relevant type.

Answer (score 0):

The asterisk indicates that it's a function POINTER :)