# Strange incompatible assignment of pointers

Tags: c, gcc, pointers

I am working on some C code.

There is a function like this;

```
void Get(double x_la[], 
double y_la[], 
double z_la[])
```

in the function body, for some other reasons I create;

```
double (*la)[3];
```

As far as I understood, x_la, y_la and z_la are pointers of the type double.

I need to "connect" the pointers involved in "la" wiht the previous ones, so I thought trying;

```
la[0]=x_la;
la[1]=y_la;
la[2]=z_la;
```

but during compilation with gnu compiler I get the error;

error: incompatible types in assignment of 'double*' to 'double [3]'

What I am doing wrong? Otherwise, how could do it well?

Thanks

P.D. Is it exactly the same to declare

double y_la[]

or

double *y_la

?

Comment: Array declarations are extensively covered in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250397/interpretation-of-int-a3/2250448#2250448).

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/859634/c-pointer-to-array-array-of-pointers-disambiguation, especially the answer about `cdecl`.

Comment: thanksa  lot to everybody, I understand it better now !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want `double *la[3];`.

As you have it, `la` isn't a pointer to double but a single pointer to an array of three things, and so each `la[i]` is still a pointer to something other than a double, and doubly problematic because you really only have one of them.

As to the second question, those are only the same in a parameter list, and even then only in an old-style declaration. Once you type in a prototype, then type conformance is governed by a more precise set of rules.

Comment: Nitpick: *"so each la[i] is still a pointer"* - each `la[i]` is an array.