# String in function parameter

Tags: c, gcc, string-literals, function-parameter

```
int main()
{
        char *x = "HelloWorld";
        char y[] = "HelloWorld";

        x[0] = 'Z';
        //y[0] = 'M';

        return 0;
}
```

In the above program, `HelloWorld` will be in read-only section(i.e string table). `x` will be pointing to that read-only section, so trying to modify that values will be undefined behavior.

But `y` will be allocated in stack and `HelloWorld` will be copied to that memory. so modifying y will works fine. [String literals: pointer vs. char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array)

**Here is my Question:**

In the following program, both `char *arr` and `char arr[]` causes segmentation fault if the content is modified.

```
void function(char arr[])
//void function(char *arr)
{
   arr[0] = 'X';
}        
int main()
{
   function("MyString");    
   return 0;
}
```

1. How it differs in the function parameter context?
2. No memory will be allocated for function parameters??

Please share your knowledge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizeof array passed as parameter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1328223/sizeof-array-passed-as-parameter)

Comment: Not really related to a discussion of the size of an array parameter.  This is about the const-ness of string literals vs character arrays, which is mostly unrelated to the sizes.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Inside the function parameter list, `char arr[]` is absolutely equivalent to `char *arr`, so the pair of definitions and the pair of declarations are equivalent.

```
void function(char arr[]) { ... }
void function(char *arr)  { ... }

void function(char arr[]);
void function(char *arr);
```

The issue is the calling context.  You provided a string literal to the function; string literals may not be modified; your function attempted to modify the string literal it was given; your program invoked undefined behaviour and crashed.  All completely kosher.

Treat string literals as if they were `static const char literal[] = "string literal";` and do not attempt to modify them.

Comment: You can even say `static const char` to have the correct storage duration.

Comment: The C++ standard, in fact, does specify that string literals are `const`. Unfortunately, the C standard does not, presumably because this would break just too much legacy code that, while not modifying these literals, is sloppy in its declarations.

Comment: @microtherion: yes, you're right about the legacy.  GCC v3.x and earlier had an option `-fwriteable-strings` (with two e's IIRC, but maybe it was one), that made string literals writable instead of constant.  GCC v4.x does not support that option; string literals are always non-writable.

Comment: I think the first sentence can be misunderstood, in a _function prototype_ the two are identical, not in a function body. I know that's what you meant, but maybe not every reader does.

Comment: @DanielFischer: I see what you mean; does the revision resolve that?

Comment: Sure. One can't misunderstand that without bad intentions ;)

Answer (score 8):

```
function("MyString");
```

is similar to

```
char *s = "MyString";
function(s);
```

`"MyString"` is in both cases a string literal and in both cases the string is unmodifiable.

```
function("MyString");
```

passes the address of a string literal to `function` as an argument.

Comment: In first case also, `HelloWorld` is string literal only in `char arr[]` case. right??

Comment: In the first code fragment, the string literal for `y` is an initializer that is copied to the stack.  If the function were invoked multiple times, the array would be initialized on each invocation, presumably using a constant initializer from somewhere else.  The array is modifiable, though.

Answer (score 2):

char *arr; 
above statement implies that arr is a character pointer and it can point to either one character or strings of character

& char arr[];
above statement implies that arr is strings of character and can store as many characters as possible or even one but will always count on '\0' character hence making it a string 
( e.g. char arr[]= "a" is similar to char arr[]={'a','\0'} )

But when used as parameters in called function, the string passed is stored character by character in formal arguments making no difference.