# C: forking new process fails

Tags: c, linux, fork

The fork in the following code does not work! It never goes into run function. Can you please tell me what is wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
void run(char* a)
{
    char* k=a;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      k[i]='s';
    printf("hi");
    return;
}
int main()
{   
    char* a="cbd";
    pid_t j;
    j=fork();
    printf("%d\t",j);
    int y;
    if(j==0)
      run(a);
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
      printf("%c\t",a[i]);
 return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
24180  c b d
```

Comment: I would use `stderr` with error checking. like this: `if (j < 0) perror ("couldn't fork")`

Comment: The value of j is not negative. I have checked it.

Comment: then give us the output of your program

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually `run()` function is called. But the problem with `k[i]='s';` statement. "cbd" is a string literal and read-only.

Allocate memory for string locally and pass the address.

like @Andy mentioned, child process crashed.

Comment: No, because the "hi" is not printing

Comment: Just put that printf() before for loop.

Comment: Arrgh...  was just typing my answer when you beat me to it.  This is correct.  "hi" does not print because **the child process crashes** trying to assign to k[0].

Comment: change `char *` to `char a[]`

Comment: @smo refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111140/string-in-function-parameter gives you some idea.

Comment: @TaylorFlores I want to use char* only. Some body mentioned allocating memory.

Comment: @smo you should read up on the difference between arrays and pointers. You can either use an array or allocate memory. It's hard to see the point of using `char *` in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the `k[i] = 's'`, which is causing the process to crash with a bus error.  The reason is, you are trying to edit the string literal "cbd" which is placed in the RODATA section of the object file, which gets stored in read-only memory.  If change the first line of main to `char a[3] = {'c', 'b', 'd'};` your program works as expected.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest adding any object file terminology, it makes your answer confusing to the OP who is still learning basic `C`

Answer (score 1):

As for the fork(), there is no problem. It's your run() function. k is a pointer to a const string, so k[0]='s' tend to report access violation.