# what is the pointer error in this code?

Tags: c, string, pointers

I am trying to understand pointers and here is a program in K&R that I am trying to implement.
The program is strcpy with code from KR.

```
/*strcpy: copy t to s; pointer version 3*/
void strcpy(char *s, char *t){

while(*s++ = *t++)     
    ;              
}
```

So to implement this program, I add

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){

    char *s="abc", *t="ABC" ;

    strcpy(s,t);
    printf("%s\n",t);

    printf("%s\n", s);
    return 0;
}
```

However I am getting segmentation error when I run it. I am sure I am missing something but not quite sure what.

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Modifying String Literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464183/modifying-string-literal)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I get a segmentation fault when writing to a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111140/string-in-function-parameter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
char *s="abc", *t="ABC" ;
```

string literals are not modifiable, however, a `char` array can be modified, so change it to :

```
char s[] ="abc", *t="ABC" ;
```

Comment: Thanks! I see the problem now!

Comment: +2 for offering solution, -1 for not explaining it.

Comment: @ElchononEdelson I thought the explanation was implied, anyway, done.

Comment: The explanation was implied, but I feel that explication is better than implication.

Answer (score 7):

Literal string values are stored in a read-only memory page; they cannot be modified.

Comment: Thanks I see the problem now!