# Which memory segment is "Hello world" when called from function printf("Hello world")?

Tags: c, memory-management

I think it's put in the **stack** because the **string** "Hello world" is a parameter of function **printf**?

If i'm wrong, can someone give and explane the correct answer?

Comment: any example of your research ? Btw, the title should be different from the question, which need to contains an exemple. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Using a text editor, I guess? Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: What is "the dynamic area of memory"?!

Comment: have you even tried anything? Technically, it's not guaranteed that a byte is the smallest usable chunk of memory, but in practice `malloc(1024)` will allocate memory to store 1024 bytes

Comment: To elaborate my previous comment, I don't use MS Paint for coding....JS can do that...

Comment: On a serious note, please show your research/debugging effort so far. Please read [Ask] page first.

Comment: There are no stacks or segments in C.

Comment: @Olaf stack memory.

Comment: @Hladni: Please provide a reference to the stnadard where it requires a stack. I'd even accept a stack of memory, hay, apples or oranges.

Answer (score 1):

String literals have static storage duration. Commonly they are stored in read-only memory. They usually go into sections called .rodata (linux) or .rdata (windows). Providing the string literal as a function parameter behaves the same as defining it as `const char *s = "Hello world"` beforehand.

Have a look at these discussions:

- [String literals: Where do they go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2589949/c-string-literals-where-do-they-go)
- ["life-time" of string literal in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9970295/life-time-of-string-literal-in-c)
- [String in function parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17111140/string-in-function-parameter)