# Why do you think segmentation error occurs at that code?

Tags: c, string, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void reverse(char *str){
    char * end = str;
    char tmp;
    if (str){
        while(*end){
            ++end;
        }
        --end;
        while (str < end){
            tmp = *str;
            *str++ = *end; // segmentation error
            *end-- = tmp;
        }
    }
}
  int main() 
  {
    char *name = "erogol"
    reverse(name);
    //printf("%s\n", name );

    return 0;  
  }
```

Why do you think segmentation error occurs at the place I singed with comment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `name` (as string literal) is for read only.

Use

```
char name[] = "erogol";
```

Seems that you are using a debugger, consider also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (sometimes it gives more details):

```
==4040== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==4040==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x40065C
==4040==    at 0x400551: reverse (demo.c:16)
==4040==    by 0x40058E: main (demo.c:24)
```

Comment: what is the technical difference between those two

Comment: @erogol, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12795948/1606345

Answer (score 1):

Because you modify a string literal.

Even though their type is `char[]` and not `char const[]` you don't have the right to modify them.