# Using generic pointers for strings

Tags: c

I was trying out a sample program to understand about the generic swap function.

/* A simple generic swap function */

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

void swap(void* xp,void* yp,int size){
        //void temp = *xp; // we cant declare a variable as void , as we need to konw to de-reference as its not specifying any size info
        // Hence used the smallest type info - char
        char buffer[size];
        memcpy(buffer,xp,size);
        memcpy(xp,yp,size);
        memcpy(yp,buffer,size);
}

int main(){
        int a = 10;
        int b = 20;
        double d=1.34;
        double e=2.34;
        char* s = "Hello";
        char* t = "World";
        printf("\n a : %s b : %s \n",s,t);
        swap(s,t,sizeof(char*));
        printf("\n a : %s b : %s \n",s,t);
        return 0;
}
```

I got a segmentation fault when I ran the above program with the function call as swap(s,t,sizeof(char*)). But if I run it with swap(&s,&t,sizeof(char*)), I don't get any segmentation fault.

gdb o/p:

```
Breakpoint 2, swap (xp=0x4007ac, yp=0x4007b2, size=8) at swap_generic1.c:5
5   void swap(void* xp,void* yp,int size){
(gdb) s
8       char buffer[size];
(gdb) s
9       memcpy(buffer,xp,size);
(gdb) s
10      memcpy(xp,yp,size);
(gdb) s

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7b64fe4 in ?? () from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
```

what might be the cause of the problem. Is that when passed as s and t, the argument is assigned with the address of the strings "Hello" and "World" respectively, and the pointer increments goes sto some other location to fetch the values.

Comment: *ahem* strict aliasing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array

Comment: @Kos This has nothing to do with "strict aliasing", assuming there's documentation stating that the parameters passed are always of the same type.

Comment: @Lundin: This could even be used for type punning (if the types are of the same size), `char *` and `void *` may alias everything. And imo it's not a duplicate (at least not a duplicate of the linked question); the two posts not from Unwind answer the question as if it were (and Unwind got the actual question, I think).

Comment: @mafso Perhaps there are better duplicates, but we get approximately one question per day on the topic "why am I getting seg faults when I do silly things with pointers to string literals".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the swap functions with `sizeof (char *)`, so you expect to only swap pointers. But you fail to pass pointers to the pointers, instead passing the values of the pointers themselves.

This will make `swap()` try to swap `sizeof (char *)` *characters* in the strings, which is not allowed since character literals generate constant data which cannot be written.

You should call it as:

```
swap(&s, &t, sizeof s);
```

to just swap the pointer values, not move any character data around.

Comment: +1 focusing for swapping pointer values only.

Answer (score 1):

```
  char* s = "Hello";
  char* t = "World";
```

Both are pointer pointing to string literal (constant string). The compiler puts that in a part of memory that is marked as read-only. If you try to change that it will result in a memory access violation.

Answer (score 1):

The pointers you pass to your swap function are string literals and writing to an element in a string literal is undefined behaviour. That is why you get the segfault