# Capitalizing letters in C using ascii

Tags: c, visual-studio, segmentation-fault

I'm just beginning in C and I'm having a hard time with a segmentation fault in my code(which is pretty simple btw).
The goal of the exercice is to capitalize each letter in a string.
Could someone please help me out ?

here is the assignment: "Write a function that puts every letter of every word in it in uppercase" (we've got to do it manually without using other libraries methods).

here is the error message: "[1]    14328 segmentation fault (core dumped)  ./a.out"

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char *my_strupcase(char *str) {

    int index = 0;

    for (index = 0; str[index] != '\0'; index++) {
        if ((str[index] >= 'a' && str[index] <= 'z') || (str[index] >= 'A' && str[index] <= 'Z')) {
            str[index] = (str[index] - 32);
            printf("%c \n", str[index]);
        } 
    }

    return str;
}

int main() {
    my_strupcase("salut");
    return (0);
}
```

Comment: `"salut"` is a sting literal and should not be attempted to be written to.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [String literals: pointer vs. char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array)

Comment: Why do you need to check for the range A-Z?  They are already capitalized.

Comment: You don't need `<unistd.h>` for the code shown.

Comment: You must decide what your function do. Now you are making uppercase from lowercase letters and uppercase letters into some kind of characters that are not letters.

Comment: You can use library function `toupper()` in `ctype.h` to convert to upper case. You don't have to check if they are appropriate characters first. But if you want to, that's what `islower()` is for.

Comment: @pmg its one of the many restrictions on the exercise haha :(

Comment: @Unknown_ questions about an exercise should include any restrictions.

Comment: @Unknown_: the tag `visual-studio` and the restriction of using `<unistd.h>` seem contradictory!!

Comment: @pmg not sure if using `unistd.h` is part of the restrictions.

Comment: [Here's `<unistd.h>` in all its glory](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/unistd.h.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is a corrected version with comments:

```
#include <stdio.h>
                                                        // you don't need unistd.h 
char *my_strupcase(char *str) {
    for (int index = 0; str[index] != '\0'; index++) {  // declare index here 
                                                        // as it's not used anywhere else
        if ((str[index] >= 'a' && str[index] <= 'z') {  // only process a-z
            str[index] = str[index] - ('a' - 'A');      // 'a' - 'A' is more clear then 32
            printf("%c \n", str[index]);
        } 
    }

    return str;
}

int main() {
    char mytext[] = "salut HELLO 123";   // here mytext is an array of char
    my_strupcase(mytext);                // that can be modified.
    puts(mytext);
    return (0);
}
```

Output should be:

> SALUT HELLO 123

Your program segfaults because you try to modify a string literal; this is undefined behaviour and results in a program crash on many platforms. You can find more detailed information about this in following [**SO article**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha).

Be aware that capitalisation should normally be done using standard functions such as `toupper`.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow this answers the question, and shows the other problems.

Comment: To me `'a' - 'A'` invites `'A' - 'a'`. The most clear value is `32 /* difference in ASCII between lowercase and corresponding uppercase letters */` (maybe using a define)