# Whats the difference in these pointers statement

Tags: c, pointers

```
int main(){
  char *c = "testando"; // how i can declare an array of characters at the same time of a char pointer statement
  int *i = {1,3,5,7,9}; // and here i can't declare an array of integers at the same time of a integer pointer statement
  return 0;
}
```

Whats the difference?

Comment: what is your own thinking ? did you try to compile ? (I suppose for *how* you mean *here*)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array

Answer (score 2):

Initializing pointers to strings was a special case in the original C language.

C99 has added [compound literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal), and you can use them to initialize a pointer to other types of arrays.

```
int *i = (int[]){1, 3, 5, 7, 9};
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I've never heard about compound literals before. It's make totally sense for me now.

Answer (score 2):

It's just syntax. String literals such as `"hello"` give a read-only array of `char[]`, as a special type. Similarly, a string literal can be used as an array initializer.

The `{1,3,5,7,9}` is not an array, but an initializer list.

You could create a temporary array of any type, with local scope, by using a *compound literal*:

```
int *i = (int[]){1,3,5,7,9};
```

This is pretty much equivalent to declaring a named array then pointing at it:

```
int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,9};
int *i = arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first instance `c` is a pointer to a **string constant**.
This is **not** the same as a **pointer to an array**.

`c` is a pointer to a list of characters terminated by the null character in *read only* memory. The pointer can be reassigned to point at another character or string of characters.

This is useful for several reasons and is thus included in ANSI and GNU C standards. Having pointer to a list of integers in read only memory isn't as useful as **enumerations** or preprocesser ***#define*** calls are generally better practice.

It will not behave like an array changing the value of the characters is undefined - try calling: `*c = 2` or `*(c+1) = 4`.

Below is an example of how a function might use a string constant:

```
File *openPipeToProgram(int flag){
        char *programname;
        if(flag == PROGRAM1)
                programname = "program1"
        else if(flag == PROGRAM2)
                programname = "program2"
        else
                return NULL;
        return popen(programname, "w");
}
```

Please note PROGRAM1 and PROGRAM2 are symbolic constants, which is used instead of having read only number arrays.