# How does assigning pointers to character variables work?

Tags: c

```
char* s_ptr = "hello"; // (1)
int* a = 5;            // (2)
```

Why does the first line work and the second doesn't? In the first case, there is no variable that stores `"hello"`, and as I understand it, a `"hello"` object (char array) is created in memory and a `s_ptr` points to first element in array. Why is number `5` not created in memory in second case?

Comment: Long story short, there's a good deal of "compiler magic" built around string literals (i.e. strings in double quotes). Other types have no such "magic", so you have to make an array explicitly.

Comment: Yes, this can be quite unintuitive, but it's the way string literals work.

Comment: `"hello"` is a string literal which is actually a _pointer_ to that string literal. But `5` is not a pointer, it's an _int_.

Comment: I tried to do this now ```printf("%c", *"Hello");``` it turns out that string literals are pointers in themselves?

Comment: @dabdya yes, you just discovered that a string literal is a pointer that points to that string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you run `printf("%p\n%p\n", s_ptr, a);` it will probably be a little bit clearer. `"hello"` decays to a pointer (which arrays often does) and that pointer is assigned to the pointer `s_ptr`. On the other hand, the pointer `a` will simply be assigned to the value `5`.

Try it out: https://onlinegdb.com/73pgzVmCJ

Related questions:

[String literals: pointer vs. char array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12795850/6699433)

[What is array to pointer decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/6699433)

Answer (score 0):

```
char* s_ptr = "hello"; // (1)
int* a = 5;            // (2)
```

> Why does the first line work and the second doesn't? In the first case, there is no variable that stores "hello", and as I understand it, a "hello" object (char array) is created in memory and a s_ptr points to first element in array. Why is number 5 not created in memory in second case?

- The first line (1) assigns a reference to a string literal (which is an array of characters) to a `char *` (character pointer) variable.  This is perfectly valid, as the string literal expression is of type pointer to char and the variable `s_ptr` is defined as pointer to char.
- The second line (2) assigns the value 5 (integer) to a `int *` which is an integer pointer, and that's a different type (not possible to convert automatically)