# C printing char pointer and char array

Tags: c

What's the difference between:

```
char *s1 = "dog";
char s2[] = "dog";
printf("%s", s1);
printf("%s", s2);
```

The first one doesn't print anything and the second prints dog as expected.

It seems to me they should be equivalent, as the right-hand side of `char *s1 = "dog";` initializes a char array under the hood, and assigns the address of its first character to `s1`. `s2` is an array and thus contains the address to the first charcter in the string. So doesn't both `s1` and `s2` contain pointers to a the first character in a string "dog"? What am i missing? thanks!

Comment: The output I got was `dogdog`

Comment: Can you do `"%s\n"` so any buffer is flushed to the output?

Comment: Aladin, "The first one doesn't print anything and the second prints dog as expected." --> How do you know it wasn't the other way around?  Try using different text.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica I already wanted to mention just that: cat/dog. I think it is an unflushed buffer.

Comment: I tried them also separately... Though I am using an online compiler I guess this is the problem... thanks!

Comment: Although they might print same thing, these two expressions aren't equivelent. Here is an example question: [String literals: pointer vs. char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array)

Answer (score 1):

Please post a minimum, complete verifiable example and not a code snippet. That is a small runnable program exhibiting your problem.
In short please do as much work as you can to make it easier to understand and explore your problem.

See here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

When I execute the program below the output is `dogdog` as expected.
You haven't included any output formatting.
In C `printf()` doesn't add a newline. For that change the first print to `printf("%s\n",s1)`.

`\n` means 'newline` and will produce:

```
dog
dog
```

.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
 
    char *s1 = "dog";
    char s2[] = "dog";
    printf("%s", s1);
    printf("%s", s2);
     
    return 0;
}
```