# What is the difference between char * and char[] as a string field in a struct in C?

Tags: c, string, struct

When I define a structure in C, can I define `char *` for a string?

Example:

```
struct Patient
{
   char *name;
   struct *App app_time;  
};
```

Then assign it like this:

```
student.name = "yoyo"; // This works when I run it
```

Or do I have to define the field name as an array of `char` like `char[20]` and then use `strcpy()`?

What is the different between the two?

I try the code above. I was able to print and change name but I did not try to get input from user using `scanf()`.

But I saw in books that using `char *` in a `struct` is not allowed.
I wonder why?

Comment: this should be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12795850/string-literals-pointer-vs-char-array

Comment: _but I saw in books that using char * in a struct is not allowed.._ You either misunderstood or that's a terrible resource. As you've already proven to yourself it's perfectly fine to have a `char*` in a struct.

Comment: The point to remember is that the structure does not manage whatever `name` points to. So you must ensure that the string it points to remains in existence for the life of the `struct` object.

Comment: And extending what @OldBoy said, if you use a pointer member and then set another struct variable to the value of the first, you get a copy of the _pointer_ , not the string.

Comment: BTW: `struct *App app_time;` is wrong, it should be `struct App *app_time;  `

Comment: Using a pointer confers responsibility for memory ownership, while having your own internal `char[n]` buffer shifts the responsibility to the owner of the `struct`.

Comment: The difference between using `char *` and char `[SOME_SIZE]` in a `struct` is the former will reference a string allocated **somewhere else** (a statically allocated string constant or otherwise) whereas the latter will embed the string in the `struct` itself.

Comment: *I saw in books that using `char *` in a `struct` is not allowed.* If you really saw it in a book, this should have been explained there.

Comment: Looking at the question title, `char arr[];` may appear as the last defined member of a `struct`, making it a **flexible array member**. The `struct` would need to be dynamically allocated to allow for the additional *actual* array length (plus terminator, if a string).

Answer (score 2):

> but I saw in books that using char * in a struct is not allowed..
> wonder why?

It is not the truth. You can use any type you want as struct member.

- `char *x;` is not a string only a **pointer** which may reference a char array with null terminating character at the end which is a ***C string***
- `char x[20];` is an array of 20 chars. It also can contain a **C string**
- `"yoyo"` is a string literal. String literals should not be modified in the *portable* code as it invokes Undefined Behaviour.

```
void foo(void)
{
    char *x = "yoyo";  // - x is a pointer to char referencing string literal
    char y[] = "yoyo"; // - y is an array of 5 chars. During initialization "yoyo" is copied into this array

    char z[20];       // defines unitialized array of 20 chars

    strcpy(z, "yoyo");// copies 5 chars to the array z
    x = y;            // x now is referencing the array y. You can modify this array using this pointer.
}
```

Comment: The information is accurate but not relevant to the question — which asks about `char *` vs `char []` in a structure.  There isn't a single structure in this answer.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler he does not know what is the difference between those two. Usage in `struct`s is the same as without them. So what is the point of your comment, except the pick?

Comment: The usage in structures is not exactly the same — though it is mostly the same.  Specifically the `char y[] = "yoyo";` could not be used in a C structure.  Using `char fam[];` as the last member of a structure has a particular meaning not remotely covered by your answer.  As other than the last member of a structure, `char name[];` simply cannot be used in a structure.  Since the question asks about structures, not discussing structures seems to me to miss the point.

Answer (score 0):

Pointers are variables that point to memory allocated elsewhere. That's it. Meaning that if you don't set them to point at memory allocated elsewhere, they can't be used or you'll get crashes etc ("undefined behavior").

Whereas a `char [20]` array inside the struct allocates memory for an array and that memory sits together with the rest of the struct members.

`"yoyo"` is a *string literal*. This is actually also an array of type `char[]`, but allocated in a read-only part of memory. You cannot write to that memory location. It's unintuitive since read-only memory ought to be of type `const char[]`, but for historical reasons C still keeps the type of string literals as `char[]`. (C++ fixed this language flaw ages ago and made string literals `const char[]`.)

That means that although you have a plain `char*`, you can assign it to a string literal even though you really should have used a `const char*`.

You can use `char*` inside structs just fine. One problem though, is that if you set a pointer member to point at some data allocated elsewhere, then copy the struct into another struct object, both structs will now have a pointer member pointing at the same memory location. That's not usually something you want, so in case you copy structs, you typically also allocate separate unique memory with `malloc` for each pointer member to point at.

There's also the function `strdup` which has been available forever as a language extension but is about to get added to the C language proper. If you would do `student.name = strdup("yoyo");` instead, then that's the same as allocating a copy of the string and letting the pointer point at the new, copied location. Where you can also write to the string or change the size with `realloc` etc. So that might be handy. Just remember to `free(student.name)` as the end, when you aren't using the memory any longer.