# C: strcmp error

Tags: c

I have two strings to compare to check if they are the same and it worked but when I opened the project today it game me the errors.

```
warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[5]'
warning C4024: 'strcmp' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1
warning C4047: 'function' : 'const char *' differs in levels of indirection from 'char (*)[5]'
warning C4024: 'strcmp' : different types for formal and actual parameter 1

printf("Your answer: ");
scanf_s("%s", &answer, 5);
//strlwr(answer);
_strlwr(answer);
if ((strcmp(&answer, "ja") && location[question].rightAnswer == 1) || (strcmp(&answer, "nej") && location[question].rightAnswer == 0) || (strcmp(&answer, "yes") && location[question].rightAnswer == 1) || (strcmp(&answer, "no") && location[question].rightAnswer == 0)){
    printf("Right answer!\n\n");
    points += difficulty;
}
else if ((strcmp(&answer, "ja") && location[question].rightAnswer != 1) || (strcmp(&answer, "nej") && location[question].rightAnswer != 0)){
    printf("Wrong answer!\n\n");
}
else{
    printf("Don't understand your input\n");
}
```

Comment: The problem is *clearly* related to the declared type of variable `answer`.  But you did not show us the declaration of `answer`.  You left out the most important part!

Comment: @abelenky 50 bucks says it's of type `char [5]` :)

Comment: just remove `&` from `&answer`.

Comment: Also, remember `strcmp()` return `0` if strings are *equals*.

Comment: Good catch @Jack, as it stands, if the user entered "ja", it'll print _Don't understand your input_.

Answer (score 3):

[`strcmp`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) takes two `const char*` and for the second argument you're passing `"ja"` which is correct, while for the first argument, you're passing pointer to an array of 5 `char`s, which is the reason you see `char (*) [5]` in the compiler error. Fixing it would be to do

```
strcmp(answer, "ja");    // & operator NOT applied to answer
```

When doing this, array decay would kick-in and `answer` which is of type `char [5]` would become `char*` a char pointer pointing to the first element of the array.

When you apply the `&` operator, you'd get a pointer to the array itself and not the decay behaviour. This is one of the few places when decay would not happen. The other two being `sizeof` and string literal initializer. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2036125/183120) for details.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you defined `answer` like this (which is fine):

```
char answer[5];
```

In that case, `answer` is already a "pointer to a string" for all intents and purposes.  So that's all you need to use in your calls to the string utility functions:

```
strcmp(answer, "ja");
```

Answer (score 1):

The warnings are clear enough. The type of the first argument of strcmp does not correspond to the type of the parameter.

The type of the parameter is `const char *` while you are trying to pass a pointer to an array of five characters `char (*)[5]`

You have to write simply

```
strcmp( answer, "ja" )
```

In this case character array `answer` that has type `char[5]` is converted to pointer to its first element that is required by the function.

Take into account that if you want to check the equality of strings you should write

```
if ( strcmp( answer, "ja" ) == 0 ) /*...(/
```

So it seems that the correct record of the first if statement will look like

```
if ( ( strcmp( answer, "ja" )  == 0 && location[question].rightAnswer == 1 ) || 
     ( strcmp( answer, "nej" ) == 0 && location[question].rightAnswer == 0 ) || 
     ( strcmp( answer, "yes" ) == 0 && location[question].rightAnswer == 1 ) || 
     ( strcmp( answer, "no"  ) == 0 && location[question].rightAnswer == 0 ) )
{
    printf("Right answer!\n\n");
    points += difficulty;
}
```

The same way also the next else-if statement has to be rewritten .

It seems also that statement

```
scanf_s("%s", &answer, 5);
```

has to be written like

```
scanf_s("%s", answer, sizeof( answer) );
```